# What is the best strategy to defeat Cid Raines?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

I'm trying to beat Cid Raines in Final Fantasy 13. He's the boss in the Fifth Ark. I've been really struggling to get a good strategy around his attacks, without much success.

Usually, I sentry myself until I get all of the upgrades, attack him till I need healed, then heal myself. After that, he typically is guarding himself, making himself a real pain to attack.

What can I do to beat him? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found party composition to be a major MAJOR issue with fighting Cid. I tried it at first with Hope, Vanille and Lightning and Cid mopped the floor with me. I tried again with Lighting, Fang and Sazh and had much better luck. Standard assault paradigm with Com/Rav/Rav, but be sure to have a medical paradigm to heal, and BE SURE to make use of Fang's saboteur skills and Sazh's synergist skills. Those alone should make the fight super easy. I beat him in like (seriously) less than 7 minutes.

Suggested paradigms are:

L-Lightning, F-Fang, S-Sazh

L-Rav F-Com S-Rav   ::  L-Med F-Sab S-Syn   ::   L-Med F-Sen S-Syn

Those three are paramount, everything else is gravy. If you've given Sazh any medic skills a fourth paradigm with L and S as medics and F as a sentinel would be helpful for those Oh ****! moments.

Comment: @Jason Berkan what did you edit? I see no changes except i had Oh ****!, and you seem to have removed two asterixes. Why? LoL

Comment: You can click on the "edited <time> ago" link above my name to see what I changed - basically I capitalized the character names and fixed a few spelling mistakes.  The asterisks are there, it's just that the markdown is eating them, since ** is used to bold something.

Comment: @Jason Berkan ahh, ok. thanks. I was just curious heh. :)

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I did not change my tactics for Cid, but that did make him a very tough fight that took me a few attempts to win.

My regular tactic was to use COM/RAV/RAV to raise the stagger gauge and then RAV/RAV/RAV while the enemy was staggered to do as much damage as possible, with a MED paradigm thrown in for healing.

However, in the fight I managed to win, I did have to use potions a couple of times to heal and I lucked out as he concentrated most of his firepower on my teammates instead of me.  When they died, I summoned Lightning's Eidolon, which revived my party and allowed me to finish the fight.

You may also want to review the [strategies here](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Cid_Raines_%28boss%29), to see if those help you out.

Answer (score 0):

A good strategy for any RPG is to level up if you are having difficulty passing. I suggest that if you are having problems, work on leveling up your guys for a bit, and come back and see what you can do.

Answer (score -1):

For me I used Lightning, Fang, and Sazh. I did RAV/RAV/COM, MED/SYN/SAB,and COM/COM/MED